# Using DownloadManager to download files to public Download directory with original filename

Tags: android

I am using this line to use the `DownloadManager` to download a series of files in my app to the public `Download` directory:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getName(), "");
```

I should add the original name of the file as the second argument, but the problem is, I don't have that name. My requests are to a url that does not contain the original name. For instance I request http://whatever.com/getmethefilewithid/1 and this page returns the file embedded in the response.

Now if I don't use the line above to specify the download destination, this name does get appended to the downloaded file (which is downloaded within my app's directory).

How can I get this name prior to making the request so I can append it to the download path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either download the file yourself (and skip `DownloadManager`), or download *enough* yourself to get to the HTTP header that contains your filename (or follow the redirect, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did based on CommonsWare's answer:

```
Integer bytes = 0;
        URL resUrl = new URL(originalUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = resUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
        String contentDispositionHeader = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Content-disposition");
        filename = null;
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=filename=\").*?(?=\")");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(contentDispositionHeader);
        if (regexMatcher.find()) {
            filename = regexMatcher.group();
        }
```